# How can I center-align Material-ui TextField text and also set a min number value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to both center align the text inside and set a min number value to 0. But that is not occurring. I can do either or but not both at the same time. I looked at the material-ui page on TextField but it was no help --> [here](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/)

```
<TextField type="number" 
    id={cells.id} 
    inputProps={{min: 0}} 
    InputProps={classes.inputText}  
    className={classes.inputComponent} 
    disabled={cells.disabled} 
    defaultValue={cells.text} />
```

I need to set a style for the text field itself and style for the text inside.

```
inputComponent: {
    height: '30px',
    width:  '71px',
    border: '1px solid #D3D4D0',
    borderRadius: '5px',
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    boxShadow: '0 1px 0 0 rgba(170,170,170,0.01)'
}

inputText: {
    color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.87)',
    fontSize: '16px',
    letterSpacing: '0.5px',
    lineHeight: '28px',
    textAlign: 'center',
}
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Change JSX a little:

```
<TextField type="number" 
    id={cells.id} 
    inputProps={{min: 0, style: { textAlign: 'center' }}} // the change is here
    InputProps={classes.inputText}  
    className={classes.inputComponent} 
    disabled={cells.disabled} 
    defaultValue={cells.text} />
```

**Reason**

`InputStyle` is not part of the API anymore.

You need to use it as `style: {}` inside `inputProps` the same way as `InputStyle` before.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Could you please send me a link to where you found out about the API changes?

Comment: I figured it out myself when looking at source code.

Comment: I am getting an warning saying that: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `InputProps` of type `string` supplied to `TextField`, expected `object`. Would you know why this is occuring?

Comment: The field itself looks as expected. But gives a warning. I can ignore it but it's better not to for production.

Comment: No I made no changes since you helped me out. Their docs aren't updated regularly I dont think.

Comment: Looks like they forgot to update `PropTypes`. It happens in big projects like this. As long as it works, we can ignore it.

Answer (score 24):

**UPDATE Material UI 5**

With the new version of Material UI, the inputProps is one level deeper.

```
<TextField 
    InputProps={{
        inputProps: {
            style: { textAlign: "right" },
        }
    }}
/>
```

Comment: For this aspect, this seems to be the only way to make right alignment work in Material UI 4 as well. (You can make the text bold for instance without using the sub- inputProps, but not textAlign.) Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/textfield-align-right-2jv00?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 15):

For MUI v5:

```
<TextField
  sx={{input: {textAlign: "center"}}}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

for right-align

```
    import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
    const useStyles = makeStyles({
    input: {
      "& .css-1t8l2tu-MuiInputBase-input-MuiOutlinedInput-input": {
        textAlign: 'right',
      },
       "& .css-1d3z3hw-MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
           textAlign: 'right'
       },

       "& .css-1kty9di-MuiFormLabel-root-MuiInputLabel-root": {
           transformOrigin: 'top left' ,
           left: 'auto',
           right: 8,
       },

       "& .css-14s5rfu-MuiFormLabel-root-MuiInputLabel-root" :{
           left: 'auto',
           right: 20,
       }
    }
  })
```

and then

```
    function ComponentNam (){ 
        const classes = useStyles();
        return(
         <TextField className={classes.input} fullWidth label="کلمه را وارد
          کنید" id="fullWidth" /> 
        )
     }
```

---